# Install .NET Framework 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

My WPF required .NET framework higher than 4 in order to publish it in a single file. I updated my Visual Studio to the latest version like I read online but still the .NET framework only shows 4.7, 4.8 versions. I downloaded the latest version of Visual Studio and tried to install it. In Visual Studio Installer, I can't find .NET framework 7 anywhere. Did I miss something?

[image]

Modified question:
My ultimate goal is to convert the .NET framework version in my WPF project. Currently, my WPF project looks like this in the Properties section:
[image]

After re-installed Visual Studio and .NET SDK to the latest version, I created a testing WPF app. I was able to choose .NET 7 framework like the image below but I had no luck with my current WPF app. It remained options of 4. versions. [image]

Comment: Install the .net 7.0 SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.400-windows-x64-installer

Comment: _My WPF required .NET framework higher than 4 in order to publish it in a single file."_ The latest version of .NET Framework is 4.8.1. There is no .NET Framework 7 just .NET 7 which is essentially .NET Core but they dropped the "Core" after .NET Core 3.x and .NET 5 was the next major version after .NET Core 3.

Comment: Anyway, you already have the latest minor version of .NET Framework installed... .NET Framework 4.8 which is definitely greater than 4.0!

Comment: Use the correct project template to get started.  Pick the one with ".NET" in its name, not ".NET Framework".

Comment: If you have an answer, please do not add it to the question, instead, post it as an Answer  in the Your Answer box below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer after 2 days of looking around on the Internet. I found a video from Microsoft website so I'd like to share in case someone encounter the same problem. For an existing project, there won't be .NET 7 available for the .NET target framework options in the Properties section. What you need to do is to download extension called ".NET Upgrade Assistant". After downloading it, right-click on the project, choose "Upgrade", then just following the steps to upgrade the target framework. Hope this help!

[image]